# Click outside of input, return false?

Tags: css

I created simple animation in CSS. Source Code here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MWOHpjTeqr_CBQaCvE4ccoY8nD8kjGFo
But I have one problem, when You click "Search" and all animation will ends and then click somewhere outside of input the input becomes circle again. How can I cancel backing to Circle while clicking outside of input?

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #999999;
}
input{
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #404040;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Catamaran';
    outline: none;
    
}
input:hover{
    background-color: #ff8533;
    transition: 0.8s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input:focus{
    animation: test 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    text-align: left;
}

::placeholder{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
@keyframes test{
    100%{width: 450px; border-radius: 30px; height: 100px; background-color: #595959; border: 1px solid #404040; cursor: auto; padding: 0px 20px;}
}
@keyframes test2{
    100%{ 
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #404040;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px;
}
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web Developing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add relevant code in the question don't link to it

Comment: You could solve it by setting a class and just don't remove that class

Answer (score 0):

In the click handler, you might alter the input class and then add that class to the hover/focus style:

> input:focus, input.classaddedonclick {

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is adding a class to your input with JavaScript when it is first focused. Although, you *could* also do it by turning your animation into a transition and giving it a *really* long reverse transition delay. Note that `text-align` can't be transitioned so the placeholder will require additional tweaking to work correctly.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #999999;
}
input{
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #404040;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Catamaran';
    outline: none;
    transition: all 1s 999999s;
    
}
input:hover{
    background-color: #ff8533;
    transition: 0.8s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input:focus{
    transition: all 1s;
    text-align: left;
    width: 450px;
    border-radius: 30px; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: #595959; 
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #404040; 
    cursor: auto; 
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

::placeholder{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
@keyframes test{
    100%{width: 450px; border-radius: 30px; height: 100px; background-color: #595959; border: 1px solid #404040; cursor: auto; padding: 0px 20px;}
}
@keyframes test2{
    100%{ 
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #404040;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px;
}
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web Developing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </body>
</html>
```